# Ошибка при запуске проекта NestJS "Error Unexpected token in JSON at position 0"

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Здраствуйте, при запуске проекта NestJS у меня начала возникать ошибка, хотя раньше все отлично работало, из-за этой ошибки запускаться проект перестал. В чем причина возникновения этой ошибки?

```
 Error  Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
```

Файлы, которые я изменял

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext): Request {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class LevelGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const level = this.reflector.get<number>('levelAccess', context.getHandler());
    if (!level || level <= 1) {
      return true;
    }
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const {req} = ctx.getContext()
    return req.user.levelAccess >= level;
  }
}

import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const ForAuth = (level: number=1) => {
  SetMetadata('levelAccess', level);
  return UseGuards(LevelGuard, JwtAuthGuard);
};
```

**auth.strategy.ts**

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
      private userService: UserService
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: "SuperSecretkey",
      passReqToCallback:true
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {    
    let user = await this.userService.findOne({id: payload.uId});
    if(!user.item){
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Не авторизировано");
    }
    return user.item;
  }
}
```

**user.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';
import { UserResolver } from './user.resolver';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { ArticleModule } from 'src/article/article.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtStrategy } from './auth.strategy';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]), JwtModule.register({
        secret: "SuperSecretkey"
    }), ArticleModule, PassportModule],
    providers: [UserResolver, UserService, JwtStrategy],
    exports: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: какой-то из запросов ожидает получить с сервера json, но получает html. посмотрите в Network

Comment: @nörbörnën он не компилируются, как посмотреть

Comment: а есть где-то место, где вы с диска читаете файл?

Comment: @nörbörnën нет такого места, я использую GraphQL (ибо интересно, что это такое), до фронтенда еще не дошел. Но помогло удаление папки dist

Answer (score 0):

Помогло удаление папки dist, проект запустился успешно